# what does base.OnPreInit(e) mean?

Tags: asp.net, events

Any one could simply tell me what does `base.OnPreInit(e)` mean ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `OnPreInit` method is called at the beginning of the page initialization stage.

When you are overriding this in your page, you'll have something like

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPreInit(e);
   ...
   // do something else 

}
```

where `base.OnPreInit(e)` calls the Page class's `OnPreInit()`.
If you don't have extra functionality to add to your page then you don't have to override `OnPreInit`

Answer (score 2):

When overriding methods e.g. `OnPreInit` in your example sometimes it is necessary to call the control/page base method, for this purposes you could just use `base.OnPreInit(e)` which will call the base class method.

Answer (score 1):

base.OnPreInit(e) is a call to the OnPreInit() method of the base class for the page you are looking at.

'e' is the parameter that was passed in to your method (presumably OnPreInit() ) and it is passed through to the base class's method.